# ArgumentOutOfRangeException and updateControls method

Tags: c#, .net

I am just a student begining to study C#, so I apologize if my questions are not very clear. I am stuck for the answer. I don't know how to code the ArgumentOutofRangeException, so the user doesn't go beyond the edges of the Lists. I have 2 of them, with two index variables. I also have a problem with updateControls. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void updateControls()
{
    pictureBox1.Image = resList[currentResIndex].Photo;
    lblName.Text = resList[currentResIndex].Title;
    lblCity.Text = resList[currentResIndex].City;
    lblPrice.Text = resList[currentResIndex].Price.ToString("C");

    pictureBox1.Image = comList[currentCommIndex].Photo;
    lblName.Text = comList[currentCommIndex].Title;
    lblCity.Text = comList[currentCommIndex].City;
    lblPrice.Text = comList[currentCommIndex].Price.ToString("C");
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Residential") //if they chose residential then increment resIndex
        currentResIndex++;
      updateControls();
    else
      currentCommIndex++;//or else commIndex
   updateControls();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if (cboType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Residential"
          && currentResIndex < resList.Count -1)    // add this condition
    currentResIndex++;

    updateControls();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just enforce the range in your `btnNext_Click` method:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Residential")//if they chose residential then increment resIndex
        currentResIndex++;
    else
        currentCommIndex++;//or else commIndex

    currentCommIndex = Math.Min(comList.Length-1, currentCommIndex);
    currentResIndex = Math.Min(resList.Length-1, currentResIndex);
    updateControls();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do with "try catch" ?

Comment: the indexes should always be in a valid range, you could argue your application **should** throw an exception if they are out of range, so no I don't think it is a good idea to use `try..catch` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    if (cboType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Residential") //if they chose residential then increment resIndex  
    {       
        currentResIndex++;       
    }
    else      
    {    
        currentCommIndex++;//or else commIndex 
    }
    updateControls();
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    //Do the things you want when this exception occurs
}
```

But imho you shouldn't be using this. You should check whether or not the end of the List is reached.

Comment: Thank you. It does throw an exception now, but I can not go through the list though. 
 
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have reached the end of the list");
                currentCommIndex--;
              
            }

Comment: @Vida What I meant was that you should only use exceptions when it really IS an exception. In your case you know that, when you don't check the index, you are going to have this behaviour. So, it's going to be obvious, not exceptional. Also it depends on what you want to do if the end of the list is reached. So, if I were you, I should go with the solution provided by @Henk Holterman (which is common practice): check first if the index is in a valid range before accessing the list.